# How to filter on a date in MySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, where-clause

I'm trying in my visitor-book that people can do only one post in one day, but I don't know how it goes. Here's the code:

```
<?php
        $user = $username;

        $timestamp = time();
        $date = date("Y.m.d", $timestamp);

        // Look if the user has written something..
        $sql="SELECT user, date FROM book WHERE user='$user' AND date=???"; 
        $qry=mysql_query($sql);
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($qry); 
        mysql_query($sql);

        if($num_rows > 0) {
        ?>

        Today you have written.

        <?php
        } else {
        ?>

        Action....

        <?php } ?>
```

I'm sure that `$date` can't be at "???" because `$date` is the current date. I need the date of the record in the database.

Comment: In what format is stored date in your database?

Comment: Would you add more detail to the question? Presumably you are not literally using `???` in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set last 24 hours date and then set the condition as greater than, here if it returns records, so the user has been wrote, and if there is no records so he/she does not write any thing in the last 24 hours. 86400 are the number of seconds in one day.

```
$datelimit = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", time()-86400);
$sql="SELECT user, date FROM book WHERE user='$user' AND date >'$datelimit'";
```

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this:

```
SELECT user, date FROM book WHERE user='$user' AND date= CURDATE();
```

[MySql: Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)

Comment: that does not answer the question at all. He is looking for : *I need the date of the record in the database*.

Comment: @Begueradj: the OP appears to be wanting to limit users to making one post a day. His **or her** code seems to be looking to see if a particular user has posted on a particular day, and thus this answer seems to fit.

Comment: any way i did not downvote your answer (some one did) because the question is not clear to me at all

Answer (score 0):

so simple!

[book writing]

```
//...
mysql_query(sprintf("INSERT INTO book(user,date,text) VALUES('%s',%d,'%s');",$username,mktime(0,0,0),$text);
```

[book reading]

```
<?php
$user = $username;

$sql="SELECT user, date FROM book WHERE user='$user' AND date=".mktime(0,0,0); 
$qry=mysql_query($sql);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($qry);

if($num_rows > 0) {
?>

Today you have writed.

<?php
} else {
?>

Action....

<?php } ?>
```